# Send apache ssl access log to syslog

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl, syslog, netcat

I'm having an issue piping apache ssl access logs to my syslog server.  I've added the following line to my apache config:

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/nc -u <syslogserver> 514" "<134>%{%b %d %X}t web1 apache %h %l %u %t \"%r\"%>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""
```

Which works great for logging the regular access log, however the ssl_access_log doesn't get sent there.  What do I have to do to accomplish that?

Comment: You need to add the same configuration to the SSL virtual host.  If it's a CentOS / RHEL system you need to modify `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`.  Go find the section that defines ssl_access_log and have at it.

Comment: Frustratingly simple.  Thank you yoonix, this solved it exactly.